# Get specific element of a given element and class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Is it possible to get an element of a specific element AND a specific class?
I want to display all `<textarea>` with  the `test` class.

I know how to get all textarea

```
$("textarea");
document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
```

Or all element of a given class

```
$(".test");
document.getElementsByClassName("test");
```

I have no idea how to get both in the same time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In jQuery simply place the selectors next to each other with no space. That acts as an `AND` condition.

```
var el = $("textarea.test");
```

The opposite of that is if you wanted an `OR` condition (textarea *or* that class), you would then use a comma:

```
var el = $("textarea,.test");
```

The basic reference for more advanced selectors is here: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use `document.getElementsByClassName("test");` because it is not supported by some browser.

You can use `$("textarea.test").val();`

Comment: The only current browser that does not support `getElementsByClassName` is IE 8 http://caniuse.com/#feat=getelementsbyclassname, but that is of course irrelevant with jQuery as it applies alternatives for older browsers.